# Adding Tracer beans in Spring Boot with OpenTelemetry

Tags: java, spring-boot, trace, opentracing, open-telemetry

Context:
I have to rewrite a parent library from Java EE to a more modern one in Spring Boot. For example, it has got some deprecated dependencies and CDI parts, Microprofiles that are not Spring compatible.

Problem:
I have hardly used OpenTelemetry and OpenTracing. I understand only the high-level concepts but I have never coded such things. I have trouble rewriting a part that involves OpenTracing. I know OpenTracing is deprecated and I should use OpenTelemetry. There is a dependency called '[Tracer Resolver](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-tracerresolver)'.

Its description from Github: *Resolver API for OpenTracing Tracer implementations. NOTE: The Tracer Resolver mechanism is only intended to be used at application startup/initialization time. This responsibility should be handled by the application, possibly using some runtime-specific support (e.g. providing a Tracer @Bean in Spring Boot, or a CDI producer). Framework integrations used to instrument-specific technologies should not use this library, but should allow a Tracer to be injected instead, with fallback to the GlobalTracer.*

In the code the only OpenTracing dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentracing-tracerresolver</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

And I found the usage in the code as:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class OpenTraceResolver {

    @Inject
    private Instance<Tracer> tracerInstance;

...
```

or

```
@Provider
public class OpenTraceErrorResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Inject
    private Tracer configuredTracer;

...
```

How should I do the same with OpenTelemetry? Is there a way to use it in such a simple way?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Spring uses **Spring Cloud Sleuth** project for implementing distributed tracing and you need to add it to your project before configuring open telemetry. By default, Spring Cloud Sleuth uses **OpenZipkin Brave**, which is different from OpenTelemetry (Otel) implementation.

To configure your project to use **OpenTelemetry** you need to decide if you will go with auto-instrumentation which is more straightforward (using agents on not) or with manual instrumentation, with gives you more flexibility.

With auto-instrumentation, you can use the java agent with some properties like the example below

```
java -javaagent:opentelemetry-java-agent-all.jar -Dotel.exporter.otlp.traces.endpoint=http://yourTraceServerEndpointUrl yourApp.jar
```

to your app execution script (ie. Dockerfile). More info on https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation

or change your **pom.xml** and configure an exporter backend in your **application.yaml** and it will automatically generate and export the traces for you.

application.yaml

```
spring.sleuth.otel.exporter.otlp.endpoint=[URL TO YOUR OTEL BACKEND]
```

*you can send the traces to zipkin, grafana tempo and etc..*

pom.xml

```html
<properties>
  <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.0-M2</spring-cloud.version>
  <spring-cloud-sleuth-otel.version>1.1.0-M3</spring-cloud-sleuth-otel.version>
  <opentelemetry-exporter-otlp>1.7.0</opentelemetry-exporter-otlp>
  <grpc-netty-shaded>1.41.0</grpc-netty-shaded>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Cloud Sleuth OTel requires a Spring Cloud Sleuth OTel BOM -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-cloud-sleuth-otel.version}</version>
      <scope>import</scope>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<!-- Sleuth with Brave tracer implementation -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <!-- Exclude Brave (the default) -->
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-brave</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<!-- Add OpenTelemetry tracer -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-autoconfigure</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.opentelemetry/opentelemetry-exporter-otlp -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
  <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-otlp</artifactId>
  <version>${opentelemetry-exporter-otlp}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.grpc/grpc-netty -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
  <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
  <version>${grpc-netty-shaded}</version>
</dependency>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>spring-snapshots</id>
    <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
  <repository>
    <id>spring-milestones</id>
    <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <id>spring-snapshots</id>
    <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
  </pluginRepository>
  <pluginRepository>
    <id>spring-milestones</id>
    <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

More references

- https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation
- https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/
- https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-cloud-sleuth-otel

Comment: just a small note, that Sleuth is being deprecated in Spring 3, so this is not the preferred way to initialize otel in new projects.

Comment: Spring 3 now uses new distributed tracing support with Micrometer Tracing (formerly Spring Cloud Sleuth) More info on https://spring.io/blog/2022/10/12/observability-with-spring-boot-3